# PHP - format html b tags into header tags

Tags: php, arrays, regex, sorting

I want to format multiple paragraphs to a better html structure

There is a database with a column called bodytext `$bodytext = $row["bodytext"];`
If i echo this you get multiple paragraphs

This is one paragraph:

— START paragraph 1

```
<b>lorem</b>
description 1

<b>lorem</b>
description 2

<b>lorem</b>
description 3

<b>lorem</b>
description 4

<b>lorem</b>
description 5

<b>lorem</b>
description 6
```

— END paragraph 1

The final result for one example paragraph:

— START paragraph 1

```
<h1>lorem</h1>
decription 1

<h2>lorem</h2>
description 2

<h2>lorem</h2>
description 3

<h3>lorem</h3>
description 4

<h3>lorem</h3>
description 5

<h3>lorem</h3>
description 6
```

— END paragraph 1

I want to format the b tags into hierachical header tags from h1 to h4
That means h1 can be exists only once, h2 only 2 times, h3 times, h4 for all the rest
The number of headers with text depends on the content, another paragraph can have only three headers with text…

What is the best way for php?

Comment: This is "impossible" with regex. And sorting... Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Comment: Sure, though what did you try, and what's your problem?

Comment: Try some very complicated `for` loop or some other loop type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your content is formed as your example shows you can use this:

```
$text = ''; // your example text goes here

$i = 1;
$matches = null;

while (true) {

    $text = preg_replace('|<(/)?b>|', ('<\1h'.$i.'>'), $text, 2, $matches);

    if (!$matches) {
        break;        
    }

    if ($i < 4) $i++;
    $matches = null;

}
```

You can see this work here:

http://ideone.com/ifmmfP